# Is it required to create IIS application for accessing application inside the website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I would like to access asp.net v4.0 web application as `http://website1:2034/servicecrm` and physical path is d:/servicecrm site/servicecrm

I've configured new IIS website "website1" with path as "d:/servicecrm site" and able to see the servicecrm as folder under the website.

Inorder to access it, is it necessary to "Convert to Application" the servicecrm folder.

**Edit:**
ServiceCRM is actual asp.net 4.0 web application containing web.config, aspx pages, etc

Comment: What is servicecrm? A whole separate website complete with web.config and all?

Comment: Yes, it is actual complete application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In order to access it, is it necessary to "Convert to Application" the servicecrm folder.

No -- whether you'd want to depends.  If you want to share login/authentication across multiple applications under the root, then you might want to leave `servicecrm` as just a subfolder.  But probably, since you've said the subfolder is itself a complete application, you should convert it to an IIS application.

Note that, if you don't convert, certain settings in the subfolder's web.config (authentication mode, for example) will trigger the *`section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level`* error.